# Query firebase OrderByChild Multiple Child

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure :

[image]

I'm trying to get all the value corresponding to the tag "Courses" like this :

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Belgique").orderByChild("Tag").equalTo("Courses").addListenerForSingleValueEvent...
```

EDIT

EXPECTED RESULT :

```
 "Key2" : {
     "Tag" : {
     "Courses":"ok",
     "Tomate" : "ok"
    }
    }
```

but it doesn't to work. (The two nodes with the same name "Tag" are not related at all)
Would have any tips? Thank you

Comment: What you're doing would require a query `.orderByChild("Tag/Courses").equalTo(true)`. But the problem is that the query won't scale. I've explained more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: I've read it. Great explanation, thank you. In my case, "John" would be "Courses" and his children would be a list of all the KEY that coutains "Courses".